# Validator error when posting a thread in Laravel Chatter

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently updated my app from Laravel 5.1 to 5.3.

Soon after this, I tried installing chatter.

I followed the instructions, found here: https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter

After following all the steps, I ran into a few problems, due to having my own user model/user auth system. But I changed things up chatter's config file, and now the forum loads fine (albeit with a few styling errors due to my main css file overriding somethings, but that's a minor issue).

The problem is that, when I try to post a new thread/discussion, I receive the following error:

[image]

which is referencing this line in `ChatterDiscussionController.php`:

[image]

and this line in `ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion.php`:

[image]

Could someone a bit more knowledgeable tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open up `vendor/devdojo/src/Events/ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion.php` and change

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

I will make sure to fix this in the source for the Laravel Chatter Application.

Comment: Created the branch `fix-before-new-discussion-event`.

Comment: The line "use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;" doesn't exist in ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion.php. It just says Use "Validator;". Changing that to what you suggest gives the same error.

Comment: So @FelixMaxime, what did you end up using? Just to make sure this gets solved for others as well.

Comment: "use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;" works for me. Just "Use Validator;" was the default, and that didn't work for me.